# If a scalar product is not specified on a vector space over an arbitrary field, is there a "standard" scalar product assumed?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, projective-geometry, scalar-fields

In Perspectives on Projective Geometry: A Guided Tour Through Real and Complex Geometry, by Jürgen Richter-Gebert we are asked to consider the three-dimensional vector space over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$, and treat the one-dimensional subspaces as as points and two-dimensional subspaces as lines.  He then goes on the speak of the condition in which the scalar product is zero.  But he has not specified a scalar product.

Last I checked, the axioms of a vector space do not specify an inner product.  In the case of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ I would just assume the author was was being presumptive, and the standard scalar product was intended.  But I don't even know what a "standard" scalar product over $\mathbb{H}^3$ (quaternions) would be.  Is there a general definition for a standard scalar product on a vector space over a field?

[image]
[image]

Comment: based on context, he seems to be referring to the bilinear map $\Bbb{K}^3\times\Bbb{K}^3\to\Bbb{K}$, $(x,y)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^3x_iy_i$ (though I would be hesitant to refer to this as a scalar/inner product if dealing with anything other than $\Bbb{R}$ as the field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t define an inner product over an arbitrary field, as has been discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/129413. For example the condition $\left<v,v \right> > 0$ requires an ordering on your field. But if that‘s out of the way the statement in the text follows from the scalar product axioms without specifying the scalar product explicitly:

$\left<v,v \right> = 0 \Rightarrow \left<\lambda_1 v,\lambda_2 v \right>=\lambda_1\bar{\lambda_2} \left<v,v \right> =0$

Where I just used linearity in the first argument and conjugate symmetry. (The latter means that you need an automorphism on your field that plays the role of complex conjugation)

Comment: It's ironic that my post a few days ago asking if the ancient Greeks really measured distance as what amounts to $\left\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x} \right\rangle $ without taking the square root, was closed and thrice voted for deletion.   "Something weaker than completeness will be enough to carry out the Gram-Schmidt process. It requires only that square-roots of $\left\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x} \right\rangle $ exist."  I claim the topic is relevant in today's mathematics.

Comment: Since I am primarily interested in real number projective geometry, I will have to leave it for further investigation, and flag Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, Box 4.3 where they discuss Hodge Duality 2-form rotations analogous to complex multiplication.